# Enhancing CRUD with selected columns and custom layout?

Tags: atk4

just learning agiletoolkit so I'm going to have some questions...

First, I have it up and running with a database with some data in it, several tables in fact. Nothing too major.

I have all the tables editable with basic CRUD but I'd like to know if it's possible to enhance the CRUD interface with layout control.

Here's what I mean:

I have a table with lots of fields defined in a Model and a page referencing that model with CRUD. I really don't want to see all the fields in a CRUD grid but I want to be able to edit  certain other fields I'd like by clicking the edit button that CRUD provides. The effect I'm after is a grid with a few columns but editable in place like CRUD does. Is this possible?

Also, I've been able to format the CRUD editor with checkboxes and date pickers for the appropriate fields but the overlay editor is too big to show all the fields in the table so I'd like to be able to format the overlay with sections and reduce the size of the fields etc..

Is this possible or do I need to go about it in another way (multiple pages with forms)?

I'm thinking perhaps of a grid layout with certain columns but I'd like an EDIT button in the column that brings up another page with edit fields that I chose for the record?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict columns shown in the grid and the form so you dont show everything in the model using the second parameter to setModel.

```
   $c1=$crud1->setModel($m, array('id', 'name', 'column1', 'column2'));
```

You can restrict rows displayed in the grid by using addCondition which amends the where clause. Putting both of these together would look something like this

```
 <?php
 class page_yourpage extends Page {

 function init() { 
   $p=$this;

   $crud1=$p->add('View_CRUD');
   $m=$p->add('Model_YourModel');
   $m->addCondition('column1','value1');
   $m->order('column2');

   $c1=$crud1->setModel($m, array('id', 'name', 'column1', 'column2'));

 }
}
?>
```

You can have columns shown in the grid but not be visible on the add/edit form when by setting the field to system(true) as suggested by mcanedo.

You can also have fields which are not shown in the grid or the form but are still accessible when referecing the page using $m->get('columnname') by setting visible(false), e.g. for the id column which is autoincrementing in mysql.

```
<?php
class Model_YourModel extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='yourtable';.
    public $table_alias='yt';

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('id')->system(true)->visible(false);
        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('column1')->system(true);
        $this->addField('column2')->system(true)->visible(false);
```

This should create a grid containing columns for name, and column 2 but when adding or editing a new field, it will only allow entering a value for name.

You can then take this further by adding to YourModel as below (and assuming YourModel.column3_id is a field with a foreign key to anothertable

```
         $this->addFIeld('column3_id')->refModel('Model_AnotherModel');
```

where 'AnotherModel' is defined as

```
  <?php
  class Model_AnotherModel extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='anothertable';.
    public $table_alias='at';

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('id')->system(true)->visible(false);
        $this->addField('name');
     }
  }
```

This will then add a drop down list to the form from which the user can select valid values from 'anothertable' and in the grid, it will display the name field instead of the ID which is actually stored in the 'yourtable'.

Answer (score 0):

If there are certain field that you don't want to appear on the crud, I guess they might be labeled as system fields,  you can do it in your model definition like this:

```
$this->addField('somefield')->system(true);
```